# Scan on IAM-scoped DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have a table that allows users (authenticated via Cognito) to read & write only their own records, enabled by an IAM policy as below:

```
"Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                    ]
                 }
             }
```

I am designing my data structure and need to know how DynamoDB applies this scoping in the context of Scan operations.

When doing a Scan, will DynamoDB apply the user scope to the table first (so the only documents scanned will be the user's documents) or will the Scan consume the whole table and then apply the policy to scope the records?

The implication of this question is how efficient a scan is - if the whole table is to be scanned then the operation will be very expensive, but if only the user's own records (a small fraction of the table) are being scanned then Scans might be acceptably efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Scan returns all items regardless of the leading keys you will not be able to use an IAM policy for the purpose of filtering based on authorisation.

As noted in the example *1: Grant permissions that limit access to items with a specific partition key value* of the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html):

> The list of actions does not include permissions for Scan because Scan
> returns all items regardless of the leading keys.

Answer (score 0):

Its best practice to design your application to use Query instead of Scans.  Scans are expensive and scan the entire table by definition.  Per the [Dynamodb Scan and Query Best Practice documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html):

> If possible, you should avoid using a Scan operation on a large table
>   or index with a filter that removes many results

What you are proposing is exactly this scenario.  Please consider a redesign to avoid this.

The IAM security piece will do the job of preventing editing of other user data, but for a single user, the scan will need to remove other users files from the scan and will be expensive.

Comment: Your answer seems to be rewording the question rather than answering it. My question is whether the IAM security policy is acting as a filter, per your noted best practice guidance to use “a filter that removes many results”. I understand that scans are expensive, but I’m trying to understand how expensive they are in this context - it is not sensible to refactor my data and increase storage requirements dramatically to avoid scans entirely if they are not dramatically more expensive and if they are relatively infrequent vs. queries.

Comment: The answer is clear - if this project is in the design/pilot stage, you would be better served to re-design and adhere to the best practice.  Go with queries against indecies and if they result in increased storage this would be preferable than than full scans which will equate to increased capacity reads and likely lower performance to your users.  Stay away from scans.